# Taxonomy archives based on Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I've generated three different custom post types (e.g. books, movies, games).  I've also created a custom taxonomy for all of them (e.g. genre).

What I need are archives for the taxonomy based on the post types. For example: "books-genre", "movies-genre"...

Is there any solution to do that? Now I've only the taxonomy archive for "genre".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a complete example made possible using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). The basic setup for this example is documented first, then we'll get to the real part of the solution using `add_rewrite_rule()`.

### Taxonomy and Post Type registration

Register the `genre` taxonomy and the `book`, `movie`, and `game` post types *(note that the singular version of each of these names is being used in this example because it's considered a [best practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103720/classes-naming-singular-or-plural))*.

```
// Create taxonomy: genre for post types: book, movie, and game
// https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy
add_action( 'init', 'wpse247013_register_taxonomies', 0 );
function wpse247013_register_taxonomies() {
    $args = [
        'public'            => true,
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'label'             => __( 'Genres', 'textdomain' ),
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => 'genre',
        'rewrite'           => [ 'slug' => 'genres' ],
    ];

    register_taxonomy( 'genre', [ 'book', 'movie', 'game' ], $args );
}

// Create post types: movie, book, and game
// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/
add_action( 'init', 'wpse247013_register_post_types' );
function wpse247013_register_post_types() {
    $book_args = [
        'label'              => __( 'Books', 'textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => [ 'slug' => 'books' ],
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => [ 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ],
        'taxonomies'         => [ 'genre' ],
    ];
    register_post_type( 'book', $book_args );

    $movie_args = [
        'label'             => __( 'Movies', 'textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => [ 'slug' => 'movies' ],
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => [ 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ],
        'taxonomies'         => [ 'genre' ],
    ];
    register_post_type( 'movie', $movie_args );

    $game_args = [
        'label'             => __( 'Games', 'textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => [ 'slug' => 'games' ],
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => [ 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ],
        'taxonomies'         => [ 'genre' ],
    ];
    register_post_type( 'game', $game_args );
}
```

### Basic URL Examples

> Based on the setup above, we'll get these URLs out of the box:
>
> **Post type archive URLs**
>
> - http://example.com/books/
> - http://example.com/movies/
> - http://example.com/games/
>
> **Single post type URLs**
>
> - http://example.com/books/{book-post-slug}
> - http://example.com/movies/{movie-post-slug}
> - http://example.com/games/{game-post-slug}
>
> **Taxonomy Term archive URLs**
>
> - http://example.com/genres/{genre-term-slug}
>     
>   *(this archive will include **all** post types, which is not what we're after)*

### Handle rewrite rules

Rewrite rules must be added in order to limit a particular genre term to a single post type. An additional rule is needed for pagination for each post type.

```
/**
 * Add rewrite rules for genre terms limited to book, movie, and game post types.
 * Pagination issue fix via http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/23155/2807
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
 */
function wpse247013_rewrite_rules() {
    // Book Genres
    add_rewrite_rule( '^books/book-genres/([^/]+)/?$',
            'index.php?taxonomy=genre&post_type=book&term=$matches[1]', 'top' );

    // Book Genres pagination
    add_rewrite_rule( '^books/book-genres/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)?$',
            'index.php?post_type=book&genre=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );

    // Movie Genres
    add_rewrite_rule( '^movies/movie-genres/([^/]+)/?$',
            'index.php?taxonomy=genre&post_type=movie&term=$matches[1]', 'top' );

    // Movie Genres pagination
    add_rewrite_rule( '^movies/movie-genres/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)?$',
            'index.php?post_type=movie&genre=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );

    // Game Genres
    add_rewrite_rule( '^games/game-genres/([^/]+)/?$',
            'index.php?taxonomy=genre&post_type=game&term=$matches[1]', 'top' );

    // Game Genres pagination
    add_rewrite_rule( '^games/game-genres/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)?$',
            'index.php?post_type=game&genre=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse247013_rewrite_rules', 10, 0 );
```

Make sure to flush the rewrite rules by visiting **Settings > Permalinks** after adding this code to your plugin or theme. If you're using a plugin, you can flush the rules programmatically using [register_activation_hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).

### Custom URLs

> The rewrite rules added above will enable the following new URLs:
>
> - http://example.com/books/book-genres/{genre-term-slug}
>     
>   (*lists only books associated with the specified genre-term-slug )*
> - http://example.com/movies/movie-genres/{genre-term-slug}
>     
>   *(lists only movies associated with the specified genre-term-slug )*
> - http://example.com/games/game-genres/{genre-term-slug}
>     
>   *(lists only games associated with the specified genre-term-slug )*

Comment: WOW! I will test it in the next days! Thank you very much for this answer ;)

Comment: You got it, keep me posted!

Comment: works like a charm ;)

Comment: one last question: is it ok to use only the term "genres" in the URL (without book-, movie- or game-)? I've tried it and it's working. But I'm not sure if maybe there are problems I don't see?! (For example: add_rewrite_rule( '^movies/genres/....)

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. I tested this setup, and the the URLs under *Basic URL Examples* and *Custom URLs* in my answer still worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. This solution is work fine even after 4 years. All the urls are working fine for me. But I am facing one issue. How to get these new archive urls in the sitemap. I have tried with Yoast and SEOPress but none of them is adding these new archive urls in sitemap. 
Is there any solution for this issue.

Comment: @Anand I've confirmed that these URLs will not show up in the native WP sitemap or Yoast. WP does have the ability to add additional entries to the sitemap, but this is beyond the scope of this question. There are not a lot of docs on the WP 5.5 sitemaps feature, but here is a good starting point: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/22/new-xml-sitemaps-functionality-in-wordpress-5-5/

Answer (score 0):

You can register taxonomy dynamically like this,

```
add_action('init',function(){

    $postType = array( 'books','movies','games' );

    foreach ( $postType as $k => $cpt ) {

        $tax_slug = strtolower( $cpt ) . '-genre';

        register_taxonomy(
            $tax_slug,
            strtolower( $cpt ),
            array(
                    'label' => 'Genre',
                    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $tax_slug ),
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                )
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how could I use this as archive or link to an archive page?

Comment: OK. I've tried your solution and added the code to my functions.php. Unfortunately it's not what I need. The code adds an extra taxonomy to my already existing one.